# How to change firebase storage access token to download url?

Tags: firebase-storage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldmAn.png) I need to refer download url, so it can show at my realtime database, but now my firebase storage did not show download url, it only show access token(when we click the access token it will copy download url, but it cannot show out download url).

So how to change the access token to download url?

Comment: Why is this question Java related?

Answer (score 1):

You have to [write code in your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) to get a download URL.  It doesn't appear in the console.

Comment: According the image that I posted, in my firebase storage show out access token and no show out download url.